# using esm modules with ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I successfully ran `ts-node` that transpiles to CommonJS modules. I used the official: [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#commonjs)

I also wanted to use esm modules following the official [esm docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#native-ecmascript-modules), but was unfortunately unsuccessful. The error I keep getting is: `CustomError: Cannot find module '/module/next/to/index/ts/ModuleName' imported from /Users/mainuser/angular_apps/typescript_test/index.ts`

This is **tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2015",                                 
      "module": "ES2020",                               
      "esModuleInterop": true,                             
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
      "strict": true,                                      
         "skipLibCheck": true                                
    },
    "ts-node": {
      "esm": true
    }
  }
```

and this is the contest of **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "typescript_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "type": "module"

}
```

I run ts-node with: `./node_modules/.bin/ts-node index.ts` while being in the project root.

What am I missing?

This is my index.ts code:

```
import { SmokeTest } from "./SmokeTest";
SmokeTest.Log();
```

And this is the SmokeTest.ts file contents. Both are at the same fs level:

```
export module SmokeTest{
    export function Log(){
        console.log("Smoke test running");  
    }
}
```

I am running node v14.19.1 and ts-node v10.7.0

Comment: At the very least your import paths need to include `.js`. It's not allowed to skip the extension, and the extension must be the 'target' extension (so .js not .ts)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding `ts-node` to the `tsconfig.json` proved ineffective for me. I updated the `tsconfig` slightly ([see node14 base](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node14.json) as a starting point) :

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "es2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["./*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I used the `--loader ts-node/esm` option:

```sh
$ node --loader ts-node/esm ./index.ts
```

I also updated my `smoke-test.ts` module to look like this:

```
function Log() {
  console.log('Smoke test running')
}

export const SmokeTest = { Log }
```

When importing with native esm modules, the extension must always be provided as `.js` for a `.ts` file:

```
import { SmokeTest } from './smoke-test.js'
SmokeTest.Log()
```

Comment: I was going crazy with a similar problem. adding the .js fixed it! thanks a lot!

Comment: Some third party dependencies also break in the same way, and adding a `.js` to the import doesn't work. For example `import { eq } from 'drizzle-orm/expressions.js';` doesn't work.

Answer (score 16):

### Switching to `vite-node` fixed the error immediately

- Install [vite-node](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/tree/main/packages/vite-node)
- Run `npx vite-node script.ts`

### Why?

- Using `.js` imports doesn't always work, and it's kinda uncomfortable (you import typescript files but you use `.js` ).

  I was trying to use `ts-node` for hours, following https://stackoverflow.com/a/71823326/7365866. I tried renaming all my imports to `.js`, and that worked briefly. However, when I wanted to add a dependency, e.g. `drizzle-orm`, imports failed (e.g. `import { eq } from 'drizzle-orm/expressions';`) with the same error.
- **vite-node is *sometimes* faster.** For a small [script](https://github.com/ben-xD/trpc-astro-cloudflare/blob/51a4b08345fd6191620087d453d45e3cb0564a16/scripts/buildTrpcPanel.ts), vite-node took **0.53** seconds, where as ts-node took 3.06 seconds. For a NodeJS application used at work, ts-node took <5 seconds to launch the app, but vite-node took ~8 seconds.

---

*Some more thoughts since I wrote this answer:* I don't recommend it in production

- I don't use it in production since it seems designed more for fast iteration, but has features like HMR, fast start up time.
- I don't think it respects `tsconfig.json`. I've found issues with dependency resolution (I still use it for my build scripts though!)
- It's relatively new compared to just transpiling your Node application into typescript and running that, so you'll find some bugs.

Comment: I recently switched from vite-node to [tsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsx) and it's faster and has a better developer experience. I'll see how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately `tsx watch` doesn't wait until the previous process releases the port so your app will often fail to restart after editing a file. Should be fixed in https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx/pull/244

Comment: So how did `tsx` go?

Comment: I haven't had any issues with `tsx`, it's been my choice since my last message for every project. Also, that `tsx` bug I mentioned was fixed. See an [example project that uses it](https://github.com/ben-xD/talkdash/blob/ad30b8f1062ef9d033d8e596ae35d8cc8419e86a/backend/package.json#L10)

Answer (score 3):

I believe with `ts-node` v10.9.1 you can use the [`--esm` flag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#esm)

```
yarn ts-node --esm path/to/file.js
```